# Simplify proposition: $((c \wedge d) \vee ( \neg a \wedge \neg b)) \wedge ((a \wedge b) \vee ( \neg c \wedge ¬d))$

Tags: logic

I know I want to end up with xor gates, but I'm stuck on how to simplify this further. Any help or hints will be appreciated... Thank you so much!

Comment: Please use MathJax in future :)

Comment: It's 4 variables.  Only 16 lines in the truth table.